# Unclear notation in Scala code snippet

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am going through the Principels of Reactive Programming course at Coursera and noticed few times a notation which I cannot completely comprehend. So I hope you can help me to understand.
Here is the code snippet:

```
def retry(noTimes:Int)(block: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
 val ns: Iterator[Int] = (1 to noTimes).iterator
 val attempts: Iterator[Future[T]] = ns.map(_ => () => block)
 val failed = Future.failed(new Exception)
 attempts.foldLeft(failed) ((a, block) => a recoverWith {block()})
}
```

It is not clear to me why in the `attempts` value definition it is not simply `ns.map(_ => block)` ?
Type of the `attempts` value is `Iterator[Future[T]]` and `map` as it written in the snippet seems to me should produce `Iterator[() => Future[T]]`. Could you help to grasp it?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. Can you point me what video from the course you took this from?

Comment: @lonut https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001/lecture/53

Answer (score 2):

With this:
`ns.map(_ => block)`

block would be executed directly, that's not what the author would want.
Similar to **Call-By-Value** parameter.

However, with this:
`ns.map(_ => () => block)`, it is similar to **Call-By-Name** parameter, meaning that the block code would be executed only when explicitly called in the underlying function.

If I correctly remembered, the author of the course was saying something like:
"Sit down, take a coffee and deeply analyse the function in order to figure out why we need to execute the `block` code lazily"  ;)

**UPDATE-------**

In the wrapping method's signature, `block` is declared as a call-by-name parameter:

```
block: => Future[T]
```

Therefore, the `Future[T]` well corresponds to `() => block` explaining why:

`val attempts: Iterator[Future[T]]`  is not `val attempts: Iterator[() => Future[T]]`

Comment: thanks, this is good and I understand that author only wants to evaluate each `block` when the `foldLeft` will do its work. But what about typing here? Is `Iterator[Future[T]]` the same as `Iterator[() => Future[T]]`?

Comment: @Mik378 I don't think `val attempts` typechecks.

Comment: precisely, in scala interpreter I have done following simple thing:
`scala> case class Foo()
defined class Foo

scala> val range: Iterator[Int] = (1 to 3).iterator
range: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> val foos: Iterator[Foo] = range map (_ => new Foo)
foos: Iterator[Foo] = non-empty iterator

scala> val foos1: Iterator[Foo] = range  map (_ => () => new Foo)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Foo
 required: Foo
       val foos1: Iterator[Foo] = range  map (_ => () => new Foo)
                                                      ^
`
So it does not typechecks.

Comment: So does it mean that Erik Meijer uses pseudo-code in his video-lectures? :)
If so I will just close my question and will take it that code in those lectures is "informal".

Comment: @AlexanderArendar I presume so. I've seen him on a few occasions being imprecise in Scala.

Comment: I guess I need somehow to close the question now.
Thank you both guys. You helped me to understand that my brain is not broken since I was thinking I am missing something obvious.
What is the proper way to close the question in such case at Stack Overflow? Should I use the "Answer Your Question" button?

Comment: I don't think you should close/delete it. Someone else might bump into this as well.

Comment: I'm voting up the question, since I'm still interested in the answer :)